# Как сделать появление рекламы при каждом 5 касаний экрана смартфона

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, uitapgesturerecognizer

Добрый день!

Я добавил рекламу во весь экран,всё работает только при **первом** касаний на конкретную UIView.

Как показать рекламу при каждом 5-ом касаний любой части экрана

```
-(void) viewDidLoad { 
UITapGestureRecognizer * BanerAppear =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerApearAdMob)];
[self.selfBannerAdMob addGestureRecognizer:BanerAppear];
self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx"];
request1 = [GADRequest request];
request1.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
[self.interstitial loadRequest:request1];
}


- (void)bannerApearAdMob{
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте счетчик и по нему показывайте рекламу. Например так:

```
- (void)bannerApearAdMob{
    if (_counter >= 5) {
        if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
            _counter = 0;
            [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
            //запрос загрузки новой рекламы, если не реализовано в методе делегата закрытия баннера/еще где.
        }
    } else {
        _counter += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! помогло но только для появления с 5+ касания, а вот повторение не работает попробовал через рекурсию хоть это не очень хорошо но тоже не помогло...

Comment: я извиняюсь что вы имели в виду в комментарий?

Comment: @Abs3akt после показа рекламы нужно подгрузить рекламу. К примеру, после закрытия рекламы: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial листинг кода после заголовка Only show GADInterstitial once

Comment: Большое спасибо! разобрался